# CentOS 6.4 Kickstart bootloader problem

Tags: centos, kernel, boot-loader, kickstart

I am installing CentOS 6.4 via a kick start file that looks like this in my build:

```
# install the bootloader (GRUB)
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append="crashkernel=auto"
```

After the installation I see this in /root/anaconda-ks.cfg

```
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
```

The problem is I do not want 'quiet' appended the the kernel parms.  quiet gives the moving progress bar during the installation instead of the detail.  I want to see the details.

Why does the installation add quiet to the bootloader when I never specified it??

How do I prevent CentOS 6.4 from adding this automatically during installation???

**UPDATE:**

**My initial post was wrong.. rhgb kernel parm enables graphical progress bar during boot.  So, in my case I needed to get rid of both rhgb and quiet.**

**Updated my ks.cfg file and added suggested editing in the %post section.  Works great now!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, it seems you can't get rid of it from Kickstart: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#bootloader

But what you can do is get the command line and the grub config replaced in the post-install (%post) section and delete it from there.

I think this should do:

> %post
>
> sed -i -e 's/quiet//' /mnt/sysimage/boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: Turns out I needed to get rid of rhgb also.  Works perfect now..Thx!!!