# Plymouth Boot Splash - Turn off switching to text

Tags: centos, bootsplash, plymouth

I am working on an appliance system based on CentOS 6. I have created a custom boot splash, but I can't find any information on how I would disable the feature to switch to text mode (switching the splash on and off) through a keypress. I do not want a user to be able to drop the splash and view the boot messages. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `plymouth quit` to your rc.local file.  `plymouth quit` should do the trick..Here is a post of mine when I ran into a problem with plymouth: [rc.local with read will not echo key strokes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105640/rc-local-with-read-will-not-echo-key-strokes)

I also found it useful to add `nomodeset` to the `isolinux.cfg` file

```
default linux
prompt 1
timeout 0
display boot.msg
F1 boot.msg
F2 options.msg
F3 general.msg
F4 param.msg
F5 rescue.msg
label linux
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img text ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg nousb nomodeset
```

Also, check out your `ks.cfg` file and make sure that `rhgb quiet` are NOT in the `--apend=` parm on your `bootloader` line.

[CentOS 6.4 Kickstart bootloader problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101303/centos-6-4-kickstart-bootloader-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but quitting the bootsplash is not the issue. Currently, the plymouth splash image comes up fine, but it is possible to press a key and have the splash image drop. This allows the user to view the boot messages, which I do not want. Would the `nomodeset` option prevent this functionality?

Comment: `nomodeset` will not help you with what you're after.  Is this for installation only or every time the machine boots?? You might want to check out the `rc.local` file..Also, you probably do want `rhgb quiet` on your `bootloader` line in your `ks.cfg` file.  I should've read your post a bit closer before answering..

Comment: I would like this behavior at all times following the installation. My kickstart infrastructure does not have any issues (I've appended `rhgb quiet vga=791` to my grub.conf boot line), and adding `nomodeset` actually causes the bootsplash to be disabled. I was thinking that I would need to supply a parameter to plymouthd when it is started (I think by rc.sysinit) or perhaps remove a parameter.

Comment: I ran into this post https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2588 looks like it's a pain in the $ss.  Here is another link:  http://www.tejasbarot.com/2009/01/19/enable-graphical-boot-with-plymouth/#axzz3W9yhx2N3

Comment: Maybe try: Try `/usr/sbin/plymouth-set-default-theme --list`  Then try `yum search plymouth-plugin`  I had a number of different plugins that can be used `plymouth-plugin-fade-throbber.i686` : Plymouth "Fade-Throbber" plugin
`plymouth-plugin-label.i686` : Plymouth label plugin
`plymouth-plugin-script.i686` : Plymouth "script" plugin
`plymouth-plugin-space-flares.i686` : Plymouth "space-flares" plugin
`plymouth-plugin-throbgress.i686` : Plymouth "Throbgress" plugin
`plymouth-plugin-two-step.i686` : Plymouth "two-step" plugin

Comment: `/usr/sbin/plymouth-set-default-theme -h
Plymouth theme chooser
usage: plymouth-set-default-theme { --list | --reset | <theme-name> [ --rebuild-initrd ] | --help }

  -h, --help             Show this help message
  -l, --list             Show available themes
  -r. --reset            Reset to default theme
  -R, --rebuild-initrd   Rebuild initrd (necessary after changing theme)
  <theme-name>           Name of new theme to use (see --list for available themes)`

Comment: Also, this would apply to CentOS:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Desktop_Migration_and_Administration_Guide/plymouth.html for creating a new custom theme.

Comment: Here is another good link for CentOS:  http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=3227

Comment: I appreciate your help, however I believe you are missing what my original question was. My custom splash works, so lets forget about it entirely, and assume that I am using the default CentOS splash.

Comment: Now, when the system boots the splash screen comes up. This masks the actual boot logs printed to the console. However, I can hit a direction key (say, up or down) which will hide the boot splash such that I can view the boot messages. Since I am working on an appliance image, I would like to prevent this behavior such that it is impossible to view the boot messages. The end result is that on every startup or shutdown, the user will only ever see the bootsplash, then the X environment, then the bootsplash, and no user input will effect this in any way. Any ideas on how/if this is possible?