# How to disable three square dots on CentOS 8 boot screen?

Tags: centos, boot, pseudoterminal

If run in (pseudo?)text mode as observed under a hupervisor KVM either VMWare, CentOS 8 displays three animated square dots at boot screen:

[image: three-square-dots-centos8]

How to disable this screen to see normal text output also during boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your grub configuration and remove the "quiet" option from the kernel line.

An easy way to do this is to remove "quiet" from "/boot/grub2/grubenv" but make sure to back up this file first just in case there is a typo which can cause the VM to not boot.

Comment: thank you @JSEvans, per further research I've found that while I can't instruct kickstart for that per design, I could apply the fix through post-install script.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101303/centos-6-4-kickstart-bootloader-problem

Comment: Any way to show custom progress info instead of disabling this screen?